# How to evaluate a function on Imported data (.xlsx file)

Tags: import, evaluation

I have imported an excel file, and I want to evaluate an expression on each point:

`Data = Import["data.xlsx"]`
which gives output like this:

```
{{f,t},{2,12},{3,200},{20,2500},{38,100},{40,2000}}
```

I want to evaluate following expression for each point:

```
Rate=EXP[(a-f)]*f*t
```

where, `a` is some type constant.
So far I am trying to use Evaluate function in mathemtica:

```
Evaluate[Rate, Data[[All, {1, 2}]]]
Evaluate[Rate, Data[[All, {3, 4}]]]
```

But couldn't figure out how to obtained values for expression (Rate) for each value. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to do the same thing to each item in a list. In Mathematica that almost always means use `Map`. I'm guessing you probably don't want to do that to the first item in your list, so `Rest` will discard that. Each item in your Data list is a list of two numbers so we define a function which accepts a list of two numbers and calculates the result you are looking for. Perhaps this will do what you are looking for

```
Data={{f,t},{2,12},{3,200},{20,2500},{38,100},{40,2000}};
a=5;
fun[{f_,t_}]:=Exp[(a-f)]*f*t;
Map[fun,Rest[Data]]
```

which instantly returns

```
{24*E^3, 600*E^2, 50000/E^15, 3800/E^33, 80000/E^35}
```

If you need that result in a different form and can't figure out how to accomplish that then leave a comment describing how it needs to be changed and perhaps we can get what you are looking for.

Look up `Map` in the documentation and see if you can understand how this works. And check these results to make certain that they are correct.

Experienced users will often use the shorthand `/@` instead of writing `Map[...]` but for a new user having those `[...]` may help you figure out how this is working.

Comment: Thank you very much, This is what I am looking for.